# Return Output in an HTML Element onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on html editor but this part is giving me a problem is there anyway to archive this? when i type in the text filed it will display an output in the div element.

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    function ColorText(){
        T = Rep(document.getElementById("text").value);
        document.getElementById("wcode").innerHTML=T;
        setTimeout("ColorText()",10);
    }
</script>
```

**HERE IS HTML PART**

```
<input type="text" id="text" onkeypress="ColorText()"/>
<div type="text" id="wcode"></div>
```

Comment: remove `quotes`. do `setTimeout(ColorText(),10);`

Comment: Actually, it'll be `setTimeout(ColorText,10);` as you don't want to execute the function yet

Comment: I did it but stile same can you show me example? `function ColorText(){
  T = document.getElementById('text').value;
  document.getElementById('wcode').innerHTML=T;
  //setTimeout("ColorText()",10);
}`

Comment: What is `Rep` ? `js` at Question appear to return expected results . _"this part is giving me a problem"_ Can describe "problem" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution, without setTimeout:

```js
function Rep(value){
  //Do your thing...
  return value;
}

var wcode = document.getElementById("wcode");
var text = document.getElementById("text");

text.addEventListener("input", function(){ 
  wcode.innerHTML = Rep(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<div id="wcode"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Codesoft, your code may not be working for 2 things:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
```

change it for:

```
<script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

---

And the other possible problem:

```
T = Rep(document.getElementById("text").value);
```

Maybe you hadn't defined the function Rep(). You have to define it and return a string value, or just don't use it, like this:

```
T = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

Besides of that, **Marcos Casagrande** gave you a better solution to your problem, please, take a look to that code.